# What is the proof work equals change in energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

What is the proof work equals change in energy that is generalized for all forms of energy such as electric and gravitational potential energy?

Answer (score 1):

The work associated to the force is defined as the integral of a force over a path. Namely,
$$W=\int_{\vec{r}_a}^{\vec{r}_b}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s}$$
Then there is the work-kinetic energy theorem which actually states that this work is equal to the variation in kinetic energy
$$W=\Delta K=K_f-K_i$$
The initial total energy is given by $E_i=K_i+U_i$, where $U_i$ is the initial potential energy of the system. In a similar manner, we have that finally $E_f=K_f+U_f$. Then, if the energy is preserved,
$$K_f-K_i=-(U_f-U_i)$$
and hence the association of the work done by a (group of) force(s) on a system with the potential energy is manifest.
$$W=-\Delta U=U_i-U_f$$
Note that we assumed that all forces are conservative in this case (this is what energy conservation means). You can see for yourself how these arguments are applied in the case of gravitational force (i.e. $\vec{F}=k\frac{Q_1Q_2}{r^2}\hat{r}$ or $\vec{F}=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}\hat{r}$). If there are any questions please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You've got it backwards. The work is defined first, and the change in potential energy (associated with a particular force like the gravitational force) is *defined* as the work done by that force over some path. For particular forces (e.g., the gravitational force), the work done depends only on the endpoints of the path and not the details of the path itself. In this case, the force is called a *conservative* force, and we can define a potential energy function that is a function of the *position* of the objects doing work on each other. The change in potential energy of the configuration of these objects as they move around is equal to minus the work done by the forces the objects exert on each other as they move around.

Thus, this requires no *proof*, because it is really a definition.